# rails with devise - able to access other accounts once logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using rails with devise for user authentication. I am able to create new user accounts and able to log in. However, once I login using an account, then I can login to other accounts also by just changing the user url.

For eg: Supose I login as a user 1 successfully, then I am redirected to http://www.example.com/users/1. Now if I change the url to http://www.example.com/users/2, then I can look at account details of user 2 and so on. How can I disallow a logged in user from being able to access other account details?

Using rails 3.2.13 and devise 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise doesn't generally handle authorization by itself, only authentication. That is, it can require that **some** user be logged in to access a resource, but doesn't check that the resource belongs to **that particular** user (this is intentional - which resources are accessible by which users is complex and depends on your app. It's a problem outside the scope of an authentication tool).

You'll need to implement an authorization system of some sort - I highly recommend the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem for the purpose - it integrates easily with Devise, and it's easy to configure to whatever authorization logic your app needs. There's a decent [RailsCast on CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) (unsurprising, given that both the RailsCasts and CanCan are by the same guy).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will certainly look into CanCan.

Comment: Can you please let me know if there are any live applications that make use of CanCan? I think I need to understand the concepts of the various roles? For eg: In my app, how should I create a user with 'admin' previliges/role rather than a user with 'normal' role.

Answer (score 0):

Devise just handles authentication, not authorization. It makes sure there is a current_user, but not whether that user should look at a particular resource.

Something like CanCan would be a good all-around authorization solution. You can find more at the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization).

But for something quick and dirty, you could do something like this in your users_controller:

```
before_filter :get_user, :user_views_only_own_records

def get_user
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  head :404 if @user.nil?
end

def user_views_only_own_records
  if @user.id != current_user.id
    head :403 # or whatever you want to do when someone tries to peek at another user
  end
end
```

But at some point you'll want to allow admins to view any user, or other similar situations, and once you start defining different access levels for different roles you'll want CanCan or something similar to make it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I accepted @MrTheWalrus answer just because he replied earlier than you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like a profiles_controller, which indexes the information in a user's profile, you can do the following:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user! # Provided by Devise
before_filter :find_user      
before_filter :ensure_proper_user

def index
....stuff
end

private
def find_user
   @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:profile_name])
end

def ensure_proper_user
  if current_user != @user
    flash[:error] = "You do not have premission to do that."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```